# Protecting scripts from post data via forms on different domains

Tags: post, security

How do I protect my scripts from post data sent from another domain? IE if I have a form that sends an id number via post to a script that say, deletes a mysql record with the id number received from $_POST?

If my domain is:

billmalarky.com

and my script is located at:

billmalarky.com/script/deletemysqlrecord.php

What if someone creates a html form on hacker.com that has the attribute:

action="http://billmalarky.com/script/deletemysqlrecord.php"

And they start sending a ton of post requests etc to delete all my records (just an example).

Thanks guys,
Billmalarky

Answer (score 0):

Yes it called Csrf

you should have hidden field   and give it  random number saved in session

example

`
   $rand = rand();
   $hidden = $_SESSION['hidden'] = $rand;

and in input field you can add

' />
 `

Then In Your Phph File Delete You Shold Check The Sent Hidden Filed And  Check It With the session calles hidden

regards